# how can save revision for carbon field in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

We are using carbon field plugin for custom field in WordPress site but problem is that WordPress is not able to store revision for carbon custom filed. Please any one can help?

Comment: This should now be available by default with the latest V3.
https://github.com/htmlburger/carbon-fields/issues/118

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to include carbon field plugin in theme.
1) adding carbon field plugin in plugin folder and activate.
2) adding carbon field plugin folder in theme folder.

```
  /* Integrating Carbon Fields Plugin */
  use Carbon_Fields\Container;
  use Carbon_Fields\Field;
  add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'crb_setup_theme' );
  function crb_setup_theme() {
      // check if Carbon Fields is not already installed
      if ( ! class_exists( "\\Carbon_Fields\\Field\\Field" ) ) {
          require( get_template_directory() . '/carbon-fields/carbon-fields-plugin.php' );
      }
  }
  add_action('carbon_register_fields', 'crb_register_custom_fields');
  function crb_register_custom_fields() {
      require get_template_directory() . '/theme_option/meta_boxes.php';
  }
```

In meta_boxes.php file you need to create metafield. like this

```
    use Carbon_Fields\Container;
    use Carbon_Fields\Field;


    Container::make('post_meta', 'Date Container')                                                  // New Added
    ->show_on_post_type(array('hotel'))  // Hotel is custom post type
    ->add_fields(array(
            Field::make('complex','hotel_details_page_content', 'Images & Content')
            ->add_fields('Entry Container', array(
            Field::make("separator", "crb_image_options", "Image Entry"),
            Field::make("image", "row_images", "Image"),
            Field::make("text", "row_image_headlines", "Image Headline"),
            Field::make("text", "image_row_subheadlines", "Image Sub Headline"),
            Field::make("separator", "crb_style_options", "Content Entry"),
            Field::make("text", "content_titles", "Title"),
            Field::make("rich_text", "content_datas", "Content"),
        )),
    ));

    Container::make('post_meta', 'Gallery Container')
        ->show_on_post_type('gallery')  // Gallery is custom post type
        ->add_fields(array(
        Field::make('complex','galleryimages', 'Gallery')
            ->add_fields('Gallery Entry', array(
            Field::make("image", "gallery_images", "Upload Image"),
        ))
    ));
```

In this way you can create multiple fields as repeater and value also save.

and Get values on frontend.

```
$carbvalue= carbon_get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'hotel_details_page_content', 'complex');

foreach ($carbvalue as $carbonvalues) {
  $herorimageid  = $carbonvalues['row_images'];

  $heroimage = wp_get_attachment_url($herorimageid);
  ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $heroimage; ?>" sizes="100vw" alt="heroimage" />

  <?php 
  echo $carbonvalues['row_image_headlines'];
}
```